# Find shortest path with Conway's Game of Life?

Tags: conways-game-of-life

Imagine N x N board. There is a robot in one box and exit place in another box. Is there any way to find shortest path from robot to exit place with using Conway's Game of Life ? I am really stucked

Comment: The game of life has absolutely nothing to do with pathfinding and I have no idea how you have connected the two.

Comment: CGL generates exactly one path, based on the shape provided at initialization. If you could iterate through every possible shape, you would be able to find the shortest path that the CGL rules allow, but necessarily the shortest path that exists.

Comment: Thank you all. @csm_dev My Instructor asked me that I dont have also any idea how can we connect them

Answer (score 0):

Although Conway's game of life is technically turing-complete, I'd advise you to try literally anything else to try to compute this sort of stuff.